# jQuery serialize an object?

Tags: jquery, serialization

Say I have something like:

```
var obj = {id: 1, name: "Some name", color: "#444444" };
```

I want to serialize that object. I tried:

```
$(obj).serialize();
```

but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: Why don't you turn it into an array first?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should use [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) instead.

### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/uzifas)

With vanilla JS, you would use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead.

Comment: Just a small correction: method name should be "stringify" (with small s) because JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned you should use .param()

```
$.param({id: 1, name: "Some name", color: '#444444' })
```

But also you need to be careful with your syntax. Your brackets don't match, and that color will need quotation marks. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eY7B/)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `JSON.stringify` to serialize your object, and you'd have to wrap your color string correctly:

```
var obj = {id: 1, name: "Some name", color: '#444444' };
var serialized = JSON.stringify(obj);
// => "{"id":1,"name":"Some name","color":"#444444"}"
```