# Converting array in object to string

Tags: javascript

I want the array in an object to be a string. can someone pl help? So im passing an array into an object and Im expecting var expectedResultForObject2 = 'name=bob&age=23&kids=billy&kids=bart&kids=bort';  how can this be attained ?

```
it("should serialize an object with another object/array in it", function() {
  var object2 = {
    'name': 'bob',
    'age': 24,
    'kids': [ 'billy', 'bart', 'bort' ]
  };

  var expectedResultForObject2 = 'name=bob&age=23&kids=billy&kids=bart&kids=bort';
  expect(NUUI.Utils.serializeForQueryString(object2))
       .toEqual(expectedResultForObject2);
});
```

Comment: This is basic stuff. Have a read on how to loop through an array in javascript. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need serialized result from an object. This can be achieved with `jQuery.param()`

```
uri = $.param(object2);
```

More information on this, you can find in [jQuery Manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Alternatively, you can make an array object a string simply with `.join()` method of the array

```
string = array.join('');
```

This question is heavily answered in SO

[jQuery serialize an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267072/jquery-serialize-an-object)